# Are predicate or function symbols with 3+ places actually used in mathematical logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, meta-math

Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. The language of first-order logic includes the following symbols :

1. predicate symbols with $n$ places: $P^n_0$, $P^n_1$, $P^n_2$, $\dots$
2. function symbols with $n$ places: $f^n_0$, $f^n_1$, $f^n_2$, $\dots$

What is an example of a formal system which actually uses a predicate or function symbol with 3 or more places? I am asking about a specific symbol, not predicate variables. It seems that, in practice, only unary (1-place) and binary (2-place) symbols are used.

**Examples.**

1. *Axiomatic set theory* uses one binary predicate symbol (membership) and no function symbols.
2. *Formal number theory* uses one binary predicate symbol (equality), one unary function symbol (succession) and two binary function symbols (addition, multiplication).
3. *Formal group theory* uses one binary predicate symbol (equality), one unary function symbol (inversion), and one binary function symbol (multiplication).

*The last two systems use a constant symbol, which may be regarded as a 0-place function symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tarskian geometry uses 3-place and 4-place predicates (at least I think they are 3-place relations, not functions, I haven't studied it in detail).  Here's an [example paper](http://www.michaelbeeson.com/research/papers/Tarski-JAR.pdf) on the topic.

Comment: Yes, if I remember correctly Tarski used the $3$-place predicate "between" (as in Bram28's answer) and the $4$-place equidistance predicate, "the distance from $a$ to $b$ equals the distance from $c$ to $d$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks!

Comment: Not enough rep to upvote :(

Comment: @simplejack Thanks for trying!

Comment: Couldn't Tarskian geometry be reformulated using unary and binary relations? Define a term $L(x,y)$ as the line segment with endpoints $x$ and $y$, a formula $R(x,y)$ meaning that $x$ belongs to $y$, and take equality to mean congruence of line segments. If this is correct, why did Tarski choose not to do this?

Comment: @simplejack I think Tarski wanted only one kind of object in the base language, to keep things simple (metamathematically).

Answer (score 0):

> What is an example of a formal system which actually uses a predicate or function symbol with 3 or more places? I am asking about a specific symbol, not predicate variables. It seems that, in practice, only unary (1-place) and binary (2-place) symbols are used.

Hmm, I am a little unclear on your question ... but I think your question is about something we use *in practice*. For example, when doing something with numbers, we might use a 2-place predicate that we want to use for 'Smaller than'. Or, we could use a 1-place predicate 'Even'.  And for functions we could use the 1-place function 'successor', or the 2-place function 'addition'.  So yes, plenty of 1-place or 2-place relations or functions here. But do we have any 'natural' 3-place predicates or functions when we apply our logic system to some domain?

Well, I suppose something like '$Sum(x,y,z)$', meant to mean: '$x$ is the sum of $y$ and $z$' could work

Or maybe someone could make good use of a $Between(x,y,z)$ ('$X$ is between $y$ and $z$') predicate ... which could be used in all kinds of domains (e.g. not just numbers, but think of objects having some location in some world)

Comment: I'm asking about a formal system. For example, set theory only uses the binary predicate symbol $\in$. This seems like informal or philosophical usage.

Comment: @simplejack Between(x,y,z) is something a formal system for geometry would use. And Sum(x,y,z) is used in formalizations of computability theory